# Empty space in Blackberry Torch 9860

Tags: css, html, cordova, blackberry

I'm making an application with Phonegap which needs to run in Blackberry, Android and iOS in landscape. In the app I already have made a responsive design with CSS to be displayed on the devices in landscape mode. I have configured the app to be started in landscape mode and it displays well in Android and iOS.

The problem is Blackberry, it displays nicely in the Blackberry 9800 simulator, but in the Blackberry Torch 9860 simulator it had a big white space at the right of my user interface. I'm setting the dimensions using javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.body.style.height = Math.min(screen.height, screen.width) + 'px';
    document.body.style.width = Math.max(screen.height, screen.width) + 'px';    
}
```

I would like to know what is causing this white space problem and how can it be solved.
Thank you!